# stop hg serve on os x

Tags: macos, mercurial

How do I stop hg serve in OS X (server 10.6)?

I started it from the terminal *not* in daemon mode. It worked fine, then I wanted to make some changes, so I did ctrl-Z to stop it. When I tried to start it again, it says...

```
abort: cannot start server at ':8000': Address already in use
```

I assume the process is already running and hasn't let go of the port. But in the activity monitor I can't find and "serve" or "hg" or "mercurial" processes to kill.

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the following to find out the process id:

```
hgt $ ps -eaf | grep hg
  502 91004 90841   0   0:00.04 ttys007    0:00.11 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /opt/local/bin/hg serve
  502 91032 90841   0   0:00.00 ttys007    0:00.00 grep hg
```

Kill the process

```
kill -9 91004
```

Next time use Ctrl-C to stop the server. :)

Comment: Thank you pyfunc. It was perfect. Two lessons learned here: A) don't use Ctrl-z, and B) using ps.

Comment: It's probably best to use "kill <pid>" rather than "kill -9 <pid>"
(as kill -9 (SIGKILL) won't give the process the chance to intercept the kill signal (and allow the process to shutdown gracefully)... my $0.02 worth :-)

Comment: NOTE: right command is "ps -eaf | grep hg" (without prefix "hgt $") - I hope this will be helpfull for someone like me :)

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl-Z` stops a process temporarily.  If you stop something with `Ctrl-Z`, you can start it again by running `fg` to have it take over the terminal again, or `bg` to have it running in the background of the terminal.  Otherwise, you can kill the server using pyfunc's answer.  You can tell if the server is still working by opening up `localhost:8000` in your browser, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the listening port typically 8000 for hg server

> sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN | grep 8000

Check the PID for hg search for hg and then python

> ps -aef | grep hg | grep python | awk '{print $2}'

Now kill the PID you found

> sudo kill -9 `ps -aef | grep hg | grep python | awk '{print $2}'`